# Why did they need to know how to code?

Tags: the-internship

In the movie the interns have several tasks revolving around code, but this doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  It confuses me because the internship, and ultimately the jobs they're trying to get, are for Sales.

I understand the necessity to know the Google software ins and outs, but coding?  That makes no sense to me.

Why did they need to know how to code?

Comment: I've not seen it, so won't answer - but it could be coder snobbery in a company that was founded and run by developers.  At times I wish all the sales people I had to work with had done *some* coding.

Comment: Some of the best salespeople I know actually started their career as developers - they know how the system is built/ how it works and therefore come across as more genuine when selling it.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers give reasonable rationales for why a movie script writer might require sales people to know coding.  Whether Google does or not, I don't know, but it is an extremely reasonable requirement, especially for such a company.

However, being a multi-decade software engineer, requiring experienced coding goes well beyond snobbery, tradition, or basic product understanding:

- drastically improves communication by providing a common frame of reference
- provides a common lexicon
- expectations begin within reasonable limits on both sides (sales and engineering)
- improves sales perception of what is possible and impossible, and provides insight into how difficult (costly) a potential customer's application might be

A joke I heard in the 1980s may shed more light:

> Q:  What's the difference between a used car salesman and a computer salesman?
>    A:  The used car salesman *knows* when he is lying.

Answer (score 6):

Before I start, I'll disclose that I haven't seen the movie, nor do I work for Google.

Having the characters code may just be something that the writers included for the movie but it would make sense: the best sales people are going to be those that really understand how the product works.

Also, internships are designed to be wide-ranging, to introduce you to many aspects of the company.  While you're there, the company is looking to see where you fit-in the best, in case they end up hiring you.  Just because you think you're meant for a job in sales doesn't mean that you'll actually end up there.  The company you work for may decide that you are a better coder than sales person.  If nothing else, showing proficiency in more than one area makes you more appealing to a company.